# SQL Inner Join Issue (Could be easy fix)

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

So I am trying to populate a  drop down by grabbing my playersID from the players table whilst sharing the same playersID with my Payments table.

When I put my query as below, it works fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT playersID FROM players";
```

But when I want to join the two tables together, I get an empty drop down.

```
<?php
include "dbconnect.php"; 

$sql = "SELECT players.playersID FROM players INNER JOIN Payments ON Payments.playersID = players.playersID";


if (!$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn))
    {
        die('Error in querying the database' . mysql_error()); 
    }

echo "<br><select name = 'listbox' id = 'listbox' onclick = 'populate()'>";  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

        $playersID = $row['playersID'];

        $allText = "$playersID,";
        echo "<option value = '$allText'> $playersID</option>"; 
    }
echo "</select>";
mysql_close($conn); ?>
```

Note I have never done an INNER JOIN before, so it may be a simple issue. The aim of the code is to enter payment information into a form and save the data to the data table. I want to show the playerID in the payments table to show that particular player paid for this product.

Cheers!

Comment: post sample data source and `CREATE TABLE` statement for both tables

Comment: @Alex I have both tables created before hand and the players table is full of entries. The payments table is a fresh table with no entries just yet.

Sample data source, I am not sure what you are looking for when you say that..

Comment: I've found [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) immensely helpful before.

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy if you have no records in `payments` then `ON Payments.playersID = players.playersID"` brings 0 records back. That is exactly what you have!

Comment: @Alex Right, gotcha. But what I am trying to do is add records to the payments table by the use of a form, and when I select a playerID it will then show in my payments table

paymentsID = 1    playersID = 4

If that makes sense.

Comment: it has no sense till you have 0 records in your `payments` table

Comment: You're saying you want `playersID` to be a foreign key in the `payments` table? You just want to insert a record in `payments`?

Comment: @DanHogan Exactly! But I also want to know what player made the payment hence the whole thing about playerID. 

On the form, the playerID must be picked from a dropdown to show which player is making the payment, along with the rest of the form being filled out

Comment: hahaha :-) finally, it seems you don't need join at all. you are trying to create dropdown `SEELECT... OPTION` there is no relevance to `payments` at all :-)

Comment: In that case, I don't think a `JOIN` is what you're looking for. Do you already have a `playerID` column in the payment table? If you do, I think what you're looking for is simply `SELECT stuff FROM payments WHERE playerID = "whatever ID you want"`

Comment: @DanHogan I have a playerID column in the payment table. What I am trying to do is add data to the payment table. I can do that fine, but the playerID that is selected from the drop down is coming up as 0 for every entry added to the table, and not the selected ID.

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy why aren't you using the simple `SELECT` that you say works?

Comment: I am using the SELECT that I posted earlier. It is giving me the list of playerID's from the players table. Now when I submit my form, the selected players ID shows up as 0 in the payments table. Most likely due to the fact that I have an Undefined Index error. I can normally fix 100% of Undefined Errors, but this one has me baffled.

*EDIT* Got it working. All is good. Appreciate the guidance here @DanHogan and Alex!

Comment: @BudgieBr0phy Then it seems there is some error in the form submission or the php

Comment: @DanHogan Yeah I got it working. Edited my post right as you submitted yours. Think I am a little tired and can't figure out the simple things haha Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to LEFT OUTER JOIN with the payments table instead of inner join, because the payment table does not have a payment for all players yet or for any at all.